# Objects being "turned" to null randomly

Tags: scala

Hey guys,
im working on a project in scala and i encountered very weird problem. This is a part of the code :

```
class Entity(val id:String){
  override def toString = id
}

class RequirementType
case class DependsEither(t:List[(Entity,Int)]) extends RequirementType
case class Depends(t:(Entity,Int)) extends RequirementType

class BuildableEntity(override val id:String,
               val mineralCost:Int,
               val gasCost:Int,
               val buildTime:Int,
               val buildCount:Int,
               val supplyCount:Int,
               val req:List[RequirementType],
               val onBuildStart: GameState => GameState,       
               val onBuildFinish: GameState => GameState
            )extends Entity(id)

class SimpleBuilding(id:String,
       mineralCost:Int,
       gasCost:Int,
       buildTime:Int,
       req:List[RequirementType]
) extends BuildableEntity(id,mineralCost,gasCost,buildTime,1,0,req:::List(ConsumesOnStart((Drone,1))),{s=>s},{x=>x})
object SpawningPool extends SimpleBuilding("spawningPool",200,0,65,List(DependsEither(List((Hatchery,1),(Lair,1),(Hive,1)))))
object Lair extends SimpleBuilding("lair",150,100,80,List(ConsumesOnFinish(Hatchery,1),Depends(SpawningPool,1)))
object InfestationPit extends SimpleBuilding("infestationPit",100,100,50,List(DependsEither(List((Lair,1),(Hive,1)))))
```

Now, when i call println(Lair.req), it sometimes prints as

> List(ConsumesOnFinish((hatchery,1)), **Depends((null,2))**, ConsumesOnStart((drone,1)))

and sometimes as

> List(ConsumesOnFinish((hatchery,1)),
>   **Depends((spawningPool,2))**, ConsumesOnStart((drone,1)))

Please, if anyone has any idea about what could be going wrong, i would love you for ever. I have no clue why is it act as it does. I have more extensions of SimpleBuilding but they seem to be working properly

EDIT:
I should also mention that the outcome changes after compilation. I mean that when i run unit test it sometimes appear as null and sometimes as proper instance.

Comment: You haven't posted the code for `Depends` and `SpawningPool` which is where the weirdness happens...

Comment: Stupid me, fixed. Thanks for taking the time and looking into this! :]

Comment: I am pretty sure it's related to the order of `object` definitions of SpawningPool to Lair.

Comment: Well, in my source file the SpawningPool is before lair so that shouldn't be a problem, i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a case of circular dependency and initialization. Here is a shorter version of your issue:

```
class X(val x: List[X])
object A extends X(List(B))
object B extends X(List(A))

object Main {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    println("A.x: " + A.x)
    println("B.x: " + B.x)
  }
}
```

This will print this:

```
$ scala -cp classes Main
A.x: List(B$@143c8b3)
B.x: List(null)
```

You can use by names parameter to allow object construction to finish before you use it:

```
class X(x0: => List[X]) {
  lazy val x = x0
}
object A extends X(List(B))
object B extends X(List(A))
```

The fix works on the small test case:

```
$ scala -cp classes Main
A.x: List(B$@1feca64)
B.x: List(A$@6d084b)
```

Based on this you may want to change `req:List[RequirementType]` to `req0: => List[RequirementType]` and add a `lazy val req = req0`.

If that works for you, we should retitle the question to mention object initialization and circular dependencies. Note this is very similar to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731389/scala-lazy-val-question/4731473#4731473).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It seems to be working! It's kinda weird that there is no compile time error, which i would have expected.

Answer (score 3):

`Lair` use `SpawningPool` in its constructor and reciprocally. But at that time, the other doesn't exists.

Answer (score 3):

You've got recursive definitions in constructors, and although I believe that is supported, it looks like something's going wrong.  Can you try lazy vals instead and see if the problem goes away?  That is,

```
object X extends C("this",that,1) { /* code */ }
```

becomes

```
lazy val X = new C("this",that,1) { /* code */ }
```